# My triangle.gs server keeps crashing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a triangle.gs free server, I logged on then after a little it says

```
error report: Internal Exception: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

the console doesn't say anything not even (my username) left the game.

Version of server: 1.7.10

Mods: none its all vanilla

I've tried restarting the server but the same error keeps happening
{ever time it crashes it puts the server offline so i start it try again but same error}

Comment: Take a look at [How do I ask a good Minecraft crash question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question), and provide the information it asks for.  That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: i edited it and added them in.

Comment: What's triangle.gs?

Comment: On the internet type www.triangle.gs its a free server host

Comment: @kingbluesapphire What's the catch..?

Comment: Chances are *extremely* good the host itself is the problem.  Have you tried contacting them about this?

Comment: @William David Edwards All you have to do is go to there website and renew it every 24 hours. So i like it b/c i can have it up for 1 day and play with a friend

Comment: @kingbluesapphire Right... so if I wasn't online for a day my server would be removed. Nope, not going to work for me!

Comment: Is your server cracked?

Comment: @william david edwards as i said i like it if i want to like play a map to with a friend. We can play the map then when we wanna play again i just renew buy clicking 1 button. This isnt for having a huge server

Comment: @kingbluesapphire OK :) But could you answer my question? Also, to what value is `player-idle-timeout` set in your `server.properties` file?

Comment: I dont think it is because i dont know how to check.

Comment: @kingbluesapphire In that case we're not going to be able to help you, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think you can do much about this: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-38565

Comment: I mean how do i check if its cracked

Comment: And im going to upload an image of the properties when i can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is team Triangle! When this was posted, we were having a partial service outage because of upgrades. Our physical machines filled up and our data centre was helping us deploy new ones.

Apologies for the downtime, you'll be good to go back on now :·)

-Your friendly neighbourhood Support Ninjas

Answer (score 2):

'Remote Host' means that it's triangle.gs's fault. 
It means whatever hosting your server was shut down.

All I can suggest is to contact their Customer Support service or wait until they get your server back up on a different machine.

Because triangle.gs is a free hosting service, you may want to either use a paid hosting service or host your server locally. Free hosting services are usually unreliable and only offer temporary servers, so going with one of those options are your best bet.

Comment: I have a second one with them for something else and it always works

Comment: It may also be that there is a limited amount of servers, so that your server was shut down to make room for another server. All in all, I'd just try a different service or use a paid one.